# Javascript: Why does getMonth() return value zero-based, but not getDate’s?

Tags: javascript, date

Can someone please explain to me why the implementation would choose to return a zero based month?

While I understand I can just add 1 to it to make it usable in a string, I am uncertain of the zero based reasoning, ESPECIALLY since `getDate` starts with 1.

Comment: There is no reasoning, it came from Java. A wild guess: obtaining a month name from a number is common and arrays start at zero, but there are no day names measured across an entire month.

Comment: Thank you minitech ... I thought it was a valid question and I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I feel this is a valid question. Good way to find the answer would be to simply go to the source code for the class. After all java is open source.

Comment: Ah man, I didnt explain well enough that I was speaking about Javascript, sorry.